# How can i add numbers together that was extracted

Tags: imacros

I have an macros for addmefast, i extracting gained points and i want count them together.

For example first extract was "8" on the next iteration and extraction would be "4" so i want to add them together.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    iimPlay(path+"Facebook Like.iim")
    iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"success_like" EXTRACT=TXT\nSET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.match(/\\d+/)[0]")\n');
    var gain = iimGetLastExtract();
    iimDisplay('Gained Points : ' + points );
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question. Make it more understandable what your problem is.

Comment: @Tanckom i just want to count extracted numbers together, so lets say on first iteration i will get "5" on next "7" so just "5 + 7" and each time add next extracted number and count them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like so:

```
var gainTotal = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
    iimPlay(path+"Facebook Like.iim")
    iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:"success_like" EXTRACT=TXT\nSET !EXTRACT EVAL("\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'.match(/\\d+/)[0]")\n');
    var gain = parseInt(iimGetLastExtract());
    gainTotal += gain;
    iimDisplay('Gained Points : ' + points );
}
alert(gainTotal);
```